# ReactJS input field in an array.map triggers rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have a ReactJS application and i conditionaly render a FormComponent based off of how many items there are in my array.

It looks something like this:

```js
myArray.map((field, index) => {
    
    // some functions
    
    return (
        <MyFormComponent /*some props*/ />
    );
}
```

MyFormComponent takes in the props and displays an Accordion for every item in the `myArray`. Inside that Accordion is a form with Autocompletes, TextFields and so on. All the components are from the [Mui material ui](https://mui.com/material-ui/). Now i use `useForm` from react-hook-form.com to manage the state, values etc of my individual forms.

Beneath I have one TextField as example of how they look alike:

```js
<TextField
    name={`myArray.${index}.name`}
     label={"Enter name"}
/>
```

The problem is, that on every letter, number and input i do into a TextField or just any field, the whole myArray.map renders again and I lose focus on the TextField i was typing in. This makes it extremly hard / nearly impossible to enter something in my form.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

**Edit**: I have a `key`property on the `<MyFormComponent />`. The key property is defined by the name of the file stored in the array. The array consists of multiple objects. each object has its own file. The filename can never be the same across all the items in the `myArray`. I define the key prop like so: `key={field.uploadedFile.name}`

Comment: Are you specifying `key` prop that remains the same for each item you're mapping?

Comment: From your snippet code its missing the `key` prop and here is how you can do it.

`<React.Fragment key={index}>
      <MyFormComponent /*some props*/ />
    </React.Fragment>`

Comment: @NickParsons  the `key` property of my MyFormComponent is set to the filename uploaded and stored in the array like so `key={field.uploadedFile.name}`. I treid different keys but I still got this problem. The name of the file is ALWAYS different. there is no way that there are two files with the same name.

@BugHunter sorry for the late comment.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar function and it was because of event listener in the form.

e.g. onClick(()=> function) should be used instead of onClick(function)

Comment: I have now changed my functions I give as props to this syntax: `move={(index: number) => moveItem(index, toIndex)}` but the problem still persists. It is a little bit faster tho, so thanks ;)